# Is there away to override flex-direction: row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that uses `flex-direction: row` and I would like to keep it that way the only problem is that now I want to put something under a div without having to nest it in.

This is what I have.
[image]

And I would like to do something like this:
[image]

My main_continer css looks something like this:

```
main_container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    text-align: left;
.div_2 {
    width: 90%;
 }
```

Is it possible to override flex direction row some way?

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: After one hour, have you read @Michael_B 's comment?

Answer (score 0):

Add the ability for the flex items to wrap:

```
.main_container {
  // ...rest of styles
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Then override the order for that second item, making it come after the fourth item:

```
.div_2 {
  order: 4; // default is 0, you might need to play with this value
}
```

Last make sure the items layout 3 across, add some new class to all the items in the flex container so you can target them together:

```
.new_class_on_all_items {
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

Comment: This helps in that in places the number 2 div at the bottom of the other 3 divs but it puts it in the center i dont know why is doesn't go to the left.

Comment: There are additional styles you could add that would wrangle that element to the left. I am curious if you use `order: 3` instead of `order: 4` if it helps. Otherwise there are several flex properties you can add to flex items to get them aligned the way you want. A good reference here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The reason "div number 2" is in the center of your flex container is because of this line: `justify-content: center;`. If you switch the value from `center` to `flex-start`, or remove the whole line entirely, the div should move to the left side of its parent.